# tcpdf issues with special characters in capital letters Ñ tilde accent

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8, tcpdf

Hi im using tcpdf im using this code to set the font:

```
if ($PDFPaperSize == 'A4'){
$pagelayout = array(279.4, 215.9);
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, $pagelayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$Heavy = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(ROOTDIR."/modules/addons/assets/fonts/$font_family-Heavy.ttf", 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

but when i print a text in spanish like AÑOS means YEARS but in capital letters shows like A??S en the .pdf file, but if i remove the uppercase code turns Años or Years, and in pdf prints perfectly ok Años without ?? so im confused, theres any fix to allow acent in uppercase letters?

pd: code attached

http://pastebin.com/QvW04Xqc

thank you.

Comment: Does the font family you're using definitely support 'Ñ' as a character?

Comment: yeah i download it from http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/ and i see the ñ and Ñ lower and uppercase

Comment: Please edit your original post and show the code where you're sending the data to TCPDF.

Comment: i just updated post with pastebin full code